# What's wrong with my Ctenanthe?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, prayer-plants

These brown spots are appearing on the leaves of my *Ctenanthe* and I'm not sure what is causing it. I am keeping the soil moist but not too much, high humidity levels and no direct sunlight.

The spots on the leaves are not crispy but almost soft.

I would appreciate any ideas on what is causing this!

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |